# If $\displaystyle 2 \int_{2}^xf(t)\,dt = xf(x) + x^3$ $\forall x \ge 1$ then find $f(2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let $f$ be a real valued function on $[1,\infty)$ such that $f(1) = 3.$

If $\displaystyle 2 \int_{2}^xf(t)\,dt = xf(x) + x^3$ $\forall x \ge 1$ then find $f(2).$

Here is my approach put $x =2$ to get

\begin{align*}
2f(2)+ 8 &= 0\\
f(2) &= -4.
\end{align*}

But if I differentiate both sides I get

\begin{align*}
2f(x) &= f(x) + xf'(x) + 3x^2\\
xf'(x) - f(x) &= -3x^2.
\end{align*}

Solving this gives $f(x) = -3x^2 + cx.$ Using the initial condition I get

$$f(x) = -3x^2 + 6x$$
or
$$f(2) = 0.$$

By different methods I am getting different values of $f(2).$ Can anyone here please tell me which one is correct and why?

Thank you.

Comment: Both your solutions are correct. The problem is with the problem itself: there is no function that satisfies both the integral equation and the initial condition (as you discovered).

Comment: @GregMartin : Thank you, for the quick response.

Comment: i don't get your second solution.  sorry.  could  you explain it a little further.

Comment: Essentially, the fact that the integral equation has a "definite integral" in it forces the solution to the integral equation to be $f(x)=-3x^2+4x.$ You can plug in $f(x)=-3x^2+6x$ and see that it does not satisfy the integral equation. Another way of looking at it is that when you differentiate the integral equation and then solve, you end up with an arbitrary constant in the solution of the DE. However, not every choice of an arbitrary constant will correspond to a solution of the integral equation.

Comment: Note that you need some additional argument, regardless. We need to assume $f$ is integrable, and then we can conclude that $f$ is continuous (why?) and hence differentiable (why?). (If we needed $x=0$ in our domain, we'd have some issues with these latter conclusions at $0$.)

Answer (score 1):

First assume that $f(x)$ is piecewise continuous, so the integral makes sense and one has by the equality of the integral that $$f(2)=-4.$$ Now assume that $f$ is continuous in order to apply FTC. Then following your work, one can solve and get that $$f(x)=-3x^2+4x.$$ This means that if $f$ is assumed to be continuous, then $f(1)=1$. As Greg Martin mentioned, the given conditions are inconsistent.